# Como fazer uma consulta LINQ que retorne a quantia de pessoas que nasceram por mês?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, linq

Gostaria de fazer uma consulta LINQ que retorne a quantia de pessoas que nasceram no mês.

No MySQL faço essa consulta:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS DataNacimento FROM pessoas WHERE MONTH (DataNascimento) = '12';
```

No LINQ tentei fazer essa consulta, mas não aceita:

```
var dataNascimento = db.Pessoas.Where(w => w.DataNascimento == "12").Count();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É mais simples que isto, mas precisa pegar o mês, não traduziu corretamente:

```
var qtdeNascidosDezembro = db.Pessoas.Count(w => w.DataNascimento.Value.Month == 12);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Linq/FilterAge.cs).

Coloquei o `Value` porque a coluna está como anulável (precisa disso mesmo?) e aí o acesso é indireto. Se realmente pode ter nulos o ideal seria tratar isso e decidir o que fazer quando vem nulo, caso contrário dará erro. Se não der erro provavelmente não deveria permitir nulo porque nenhum o é. Poderia decidir usando o `HasValaue` ou pegar o valor com o `GetValueOrDefault()`.

Comment: Aqui pra mim no lugar de Month, só aparece essas opções: Equals, GetHashCode, GetType, GetValueorDefault, HasValue, ToString e Value.

Comment: Então tem algo errado no seu modelo, o problema não é com o LINQ, você está recebendo um `Nullable` e não um `DateTime` como era de se esperar. Tenta ver se tem no `Value`.

Comment: Isso mesmo, estava em ".Value.Month".